# Use find command and if statement in a simple bash script

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, find, filesize

I have a directory in `/root/xml-test/` which contains `.xml` files and they are 99MB each.

I'm using an `if TEST` statement to check if the size is larger than `$a`.

The problem is... the if statement always results in the A, larger than B - even if I choose a small number for A - such as 1.

Here is the script to test yourself.  There is a URL in the comments to create a file of any size for your testing.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#This will check the size of the XML files in /root/xml-test


# Script Test Procedures
# Create file of any size
#https://www.ostechnix.com/create-files-certain-size-linux/

xmlpath='/root/xml-test/.'

size=$(find $xmlpath -type f -name '*.xml' -exec du -c {} + | grep total$) ; total=$(echo $size |  cut -c 1- | rev | cut -c 7- | rev)

b=$total
echo $total 'size in blocks' &&  echo "enter a second number";'

read a ;
echo "a=$a";
echo b=$total;

if [ $a > $b ];
then
    echo "a is greater than b";
else
    echo "b is greater than a";
fi;
```

Comment: https://shellcheck.net to validate  your script. That `[ $a > $b ]` created a filename or truncate if the file already exist,

Comment: Look into `find`'s `-printf` option and its `%s` format specifier (size in bytes).

Comment: `[ $a > $b ]` doesn't do what you want at all; `>` is treated as an output redirect rather than a comparison operator. `[ $a \> $b ]` is closer, but it does lexical comparison rather than numeric (i.e. `[ 10 \> 2 ]` is false, because "1" comes before "2" in character sorting order). Also, having variable references without double-quotes around them can have weird effects. What you really want is `[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]`. `total$` should also be in quotes (probably single, so `$` can't be mistaken for shell syntax). And (pet peeve) you don't need semicolons at the end of lines.

Comment: I've fixed the code block formatting; syntax highlighting makes it more obvious now that there's a stray single quote in there.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @gordon-davisson the solution to the problem was changing the following:

`if [ $a > $b ];`

`if [ $a \> $b ];`

A is now Greater than B

B can be Greater than A

Great Job!

Comment: >What you really want is `[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]`. `total$` should also be in quotes (probably single, so $ can't be mistaken for shell syntax). And (pet peeve) you don't need semicolons at the end of lines.


I will also test this too...

Comment: Now you should apply the rest of the advice as well: use `-gt` instead of `\>` for numerical comparison, and quote your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is integer to integer comparision:

`[ "$a" -gt "$b" ]`

The man pages define the `test` command with the `-gt` option as:

```
   INTEGER1 -gt INTEGER2
          INTEGER1 is greater than INTEGER2
```